# Inserting data using Linq C# with MVC 3 Architecture in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, linq

I m inserting data using controller,

SignUpcontroller.cs

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(SignUpModel sm)
{

using(DataClassesDataContext dc= new DataClassesDataContext())
{
Dummytable dm= new Dummytable();
{
dm.Name=sm.password;
}
//then conncetion string and submit
}
}
```

and redirection

My question is, is it correct to write this code in the controller module or do i need to write it in models module, if i need to write it in models module then how to define the setter help me out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for the Implementation to work i jst give memory of class to interface with the help of casting from the controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(SignUpModel sm)
{
ISignUpModel ISign= (ISignUpModel)this.sm;
ISign.Insert(sm);
}
```

thanks everyone else, because of you all i learn this :)

and at the SignUpModel.cs, is normal "Interface named as ISignUp with Insert method" Implementation

Answer (score 3):

It is better practice to move all data access code in a data access layer. So simply put this code in a separate class that you could reference and call from your controller. For example you could define an interface that will define the different operations:

```
public interface IRepository
{
    void Insert(SignUpModel model);
}
```

and then have a specific implementation that is working with the data access technology you are using (EF for example):

```
public class RepositoryEF : IRepository
{
    public void Insert(SignUpModel model)
    {
        using(DataClassesDataContext dc= new DataClassesDataContext())
        {
            Dummytable dm = new Dummytable();
            dm.Name = sm.password;
        }
    }
}
```

and the next step is to have your controller take this repository as constructor dependency:

```
public class SomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly IRepository repo;
    public SomeController(IRepository repo)
    {
        this.repo = repo;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(SignUpModel sm)
    {
        this.repo.Insert(sm);

        ...
    }
}
```

Now all that's left is pick up some DI framework and wire up the dependencies.

This way you have a clear separation between your controller logic and the data access layer. This would allow you to unit test the various layers of your application in separation.

Comment: in signupmodel.cs where i have written the getter setter? is it ok to include on more class in that module?

Comment: You could define the interface and the implementation in a separate .cs files.

Comment: is interface is compulsory needed?

Comment: Problem with inserting:

dc.Dummytables.InsertOnSubmit(dm);

Answer (score 0):

first question is Where is your  `DataAccessLayer` ?

So the better practise is write the codes in another one class for read and write database values .

The `controller` have only  for `UI` logics

and you can use `Interface` for increase reusability  reason and Unit Testing .

[image]

Comment: I have used DataClasses.dbml

Answer (score 0):

This is not common to use for vital data storing/accessing like signup. Consider web security tools and don't work directly with this type of data. Or change your meaning to work with common data.

Comment: I m new with MVC i just want to know where should i put that code?